# Algorithm that calculates optimal change-making, sort of

Tags: excel, algorithm, vba

#### The TL;DR:

*I'm attempting to write a very basic macro in VBA that calculates the optimal amount of currency to get to a certain total.  Simplest way I could explain my problem.*

---

#### The more in-depth:

I have a register that starts off at $175 every day.  At the close of the day, my managers have to close out the register, meaning count the deposit/tips and get the register back to $175 for the next day.  For whatever reason some have issues with this.  I was bored and wanted to see if I could find an easy solution for them with Excel and VBA.

I currently have the following 'planned' for this:
*Input fields*

1. Change (in register)
2. $1's
3. $5's
4. $10's
5. $20's
6. $50's
7. $100's

*Output*

Amount of 1's, 5's, 10's, etc to put into register to get to $175.00

---

#### My thoughts:

Essentially I'm trying to get an output that will tell me how many of each denomination bill I need to put into the register based on what I have (the input amounts) and giving more priority to 1's than 5's, and so on.

I'm just stumped on how to approach this. I haven't programmed at all in a few years and it's just not coming to me at the moment.

A real number example would be:

*Input*

```
Change = $11.00
$1's = $33.00
$5's = $20.00
$10's = $10.00
$20's = $300.00
$50's = $100.00
$100's = $0.00
```

*Output*

```
$1's = $29.00
$5's = $15.00
$10's = $0.00
$20's = $120.00
```

---

#### My code so far:

```
Private Sub CalculateButton_Click()
'Assigning Variables
Dim cha As Currency
Dim A1 As Currency
Dim A5 As Currency
Dim A10 As Currency
Dim A20 As Currency
Dim A50 As Currency
Dim A100 As Currency

'Setting Variables values

cha = Range("b5").Value
A1 = Range("b6").Value
A5 = Range("b7").Value
A10 = Range("b8").Value
A20 = Range("b9").Value
A50 = Range("b10").Value
A100 = Range("b11").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Start with the highest denomination and work down when calculating the optimal way to give change for each possible amount (within your sample range).  Then either take the average, max, or some other weighting based on how you predict situations where change is given (i.e., people are more likely to carry a single 20 as opposed to 20 singles).

Comment: @Comintern Oh I already know how to do this on my own, it's coding it I don't fully grasp.  Some sort of loop that deducts the amount of bills taken from the total perhaps?

Comment: There will usually be *many* ways to get the register back to $175, but you haven't said what you're trying to optimise, so we don't know which approach to use.  If you just want *any* solution, I'd suggest making a loop in which you repeatedly add a single bill of the highest denomination that is both (a) available and (b) leaves the register <= $175.  The loop stops when the register reaches $175.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Guess I wasn't very clear above, apologies.  Worked too long yesterday.  But I am trying to optimize lowest bills up, as in I want more 1$ than 5's etc.  I shall try out that solution